# Angular4: Display subProperty of an object in a View

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-template

I'm quite new in angular4, and I've some issue to display some information.

I've an angular service, which makes an HTTP request to my webservice:

```
@Injectable()
export class AstroService {

    constructor(private _http: Http) {}
    get() {
        return this._http.get('api/astro/get')
            .map((res: Response) => {
                return  res.json();
            });
    } 
}
```

In my component, I query the service:

```
export class DisplayComponent {
    horoscopes: any = null;

    constructor(private astroService:AstroService) {
        this.astroService.get()
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.horoscopes = data;
            });
    }
}
```

The console.log display the expected data:
[image]

But in my component's view, when I try to display it:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red">display Component</div>

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let horosocope of horoscopes">
        {{horoscope.sign.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

I got my 12 bullet points, but nothing else and the chrome console tells me that it doesn't anything about "sign":

```
VM4824 DisplayComponent.ngfactory.js:8 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sign' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (VM4824 DisplayComponent.ngfactory.js:11)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14727)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13841)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14145)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13837)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14119)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13842)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
```

What did I do wrong? Sorry, I feel it's a dum question, but I can't figure out what I missed.

Comment: What do you see if you write `<li *ngFor="let horosocope of horoscopes">{{horoscope | json}}</li>` ?

Comment: almost the same things, 12 empty `<li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a misstyping issue !

```
<li *ngFor="let horosocope of horoscopes">
    {{horoscope.sign.name}}
</li>
```

should be

```
<li *ngFor="let horosocope of horoscopes">
    {{horosocope.sign.name}}
</li>
```

It's time to take a break :-).

Comment: "G-g-g-g-g-g-god-like!", you rock! I searched for this during hours! Didn't think I would got this error in this case(but more like "horoscope not existing"

Answer (score 0):

try add question marks

```
  <div style="border: 1px solid red">display Component</div>

 <ul>
     <li *ngFor="let horoscope of horoscopes">
       {{horoscope?.sign?.name}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

When Angular renders the view before horoscope got a value assigned, it causes an exception. ?. stops evaluating when horoscope is null or undefined, which usually happens when data is fetched async, for example from the server which can take quite some time.

Comment: Now I don't have an exception, but then, nothing is added to my html, it only looks like `<ul><li></li><li></li><li></li>...</ul>`(with additional _ng-content-c8)

Comment: looks like sign is the property that is an object in which you have a "name", so you should access it properly

Comment: Exactly, but how to access it "properly" ?

Comment: {{horoscope?.sign &&  horoscope?.sign?.name}} can you try this